# Is it possible to access keys for Firebase rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Data:

```
 invitations:{
    user1:{
       group1: true
    }
 }
```

New Data:

```
connectedGroups:{
   user1:{
     group1: true
   }
}
```

Rules:

```
connectedGroups:{
   ".read": "auth != null",
   "$newUser":{
      ".write": "auth.uid == $newUser &&//group in new data == group in invitations
    }
}
```

I've been trying for days to work out how to compare these keys.  Is it even possible or do I need to restructure my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `parent` and `child` function of `data` or `newData` to look up other properties:

```
"connectedGroups": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$newUser": {
     ".write": "auth.uid == $newUser",
     "$newGroup": {
       ".validate": "newData.val() == true && data.parent().child('invitations').child($newUser).child($newGroup) == true"
     }
  }
}
```

The `validate` rule checks whether the path `/invitations/$newUser/$newGroup` is already present and contains `true` (assuming `invitations` and `connectedGroups` are both top-level paths)

See [the docs on Security & Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#referencing_data_in_other_paths) for further information.
Using [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) (beta) makes writing these path look-up and type checking rules simpler.